# South: changing ForeingKey

Tags: django, django-south

i had a `profile` field in todo models which a `ForeignKey` to Profile model

Instead of using profile i want to use the `user` field of User model as a `ForeignKey` .

Steps:

1. I have removed the `profile` field from todo model, created and applied migration for that. 
   Works fine, profile field do not exist in database.

2, I added `user` field as a `ForeignKey` in todos models .

When doing `python manage.py schemamigration todos --auto`
gives response like:

**Nothing seems to have changed.**

what am missing here ?

Comment: Run `python manage.py migrate todos`

Comment: but that come into play after migration is created for added ForeignKey, right ?